# Cordova android filesystem difficulties

Tags: android, file, cordova, filesystems

We're developing an android application with cordova were files will be synchronized. 
Cordova is up to date, but the problem is that our files are saved in the main storage directory.

The file url looks like:
`file:///storage/emulated/0/{our_directory}//`

After a cordova update we were forced to set 
`<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />` in the config.xml, for still finding our files.

Now we really would like to have our files in the internal data directory.
So if course we just could remove the "Compatibility" setting in the config.xml but then all files would be invisible.

If we change to internal data directory we are having two problems:

1. In a transition period we need to have access on both directories (Compatibility: `file:///storage/emulated/0/{our_directory}//` and the new correct internal data directory: `file:///data/user/0/{our_app_id}/files/files/{our_directory}//`). 
   If we change to interal `window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,0,fn)` delivers the root directory of the internal app data directory. So how can I read or write to files which are not in this directory? I found out, that `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory`delivers the old path. Any ideas on how to access to both directories?
2. The other thing is, that we may would like to move all the files from the old directory into the new correct internal app data directory. Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the URL you want to store and retrieve files from you can use:

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(URL, callback);

The callback will be passed the directory entry.

To move files you can use the fileEntry method moveTo.

entry.moveTo(parentEntry, "newFile.txt", success, fail);

I know this documentation is for Cordova 3.3.0 but I believe it is still relevant.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova/file/fileentry/fileentry.html

Comment: Thanks, seems like a good idea! With the internal setting we are having another problem: External file open plugins like (https://github.com/critical/cordova-external-file-open) wont work, because other applications do not have access to the files of the internal application data directory. Do you have a solution for this problem too?

Comment: Yes, when you have the fileEntry use the file() method from the same documentation in my answer. Then you can pass this to the file opener plugin.